# How to create a log analytics query to track cpu usage over a period of time

Tags: windows, azure

I need to create an alert if an azure VM has a CPU Usage of 90% for at least 30 minutes, how can I create a query in Azure Log Analytics for this ?

Comment: i worked it out myself :

Answer (score 0):

Perf
| where CounterName == “% Processor Time” and InstanceName == “_Total”
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer,  bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)

ENSURE you have added the performance counters  ***Processor(*)% Privileged Time*** and ***Process(*)% Processor Time*** in Log Analytics by checking Log Analytics > Agents configuration > Windows Performance Counters. If you do not add these counters you will get 0 results